# How to not display posts with a certain tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I have this code running, in order to get the posts.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php // The loop  ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to return just the posts which do not have some specifics tags.
How could I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional [`has_tag()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag) function:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php // The loop  ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php if( ! has_tag( 'tag-name' ) ) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentythirteen_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that `has_tag()` accepts a single tag name or an array of tags (so if there are multiple tags that you want to ignore, you could use `if( has_tag( array( 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', ) ) )` in the code above. Also, `has_tag()` can only be used in The Loop. (**Correction:** per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_tag, the requirement that you be in The Loop is only true up to WP version 2.7.)

Comment: you rock dude! it couldn't work better! thanks a lot!

Comment: If this works for you, please mark the answer as **Accepted** -- there should be a checkmark to the left of the question so that you can do this.  See [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args=array("tag__not_in"=>array(1,2,3));
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Just pass tag ids

```
 array("tag__not_in"=>array(1,2,3));
```